# Drawing custom shapes in an iOS game built upon cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I'm looking to draw a custom shape (say, a solid rectangle) using openGL ES in an iOS game built upon the Cocos2d framework.  In [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166430/how-can-i-implement-a-virtual-joystick-for-a-cocos2d-game-outside-the-cocos2d-env), I saw a suggestion to use `[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView`; however, I am unsure as to how to go about this.  Perhaps someone can provide an example or point me to some sample code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tutorials I can recommend for doing this, depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Generating Textures using CCRenderTexture - [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture)

Generating Textures using OpenGL - [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures)